# how to multiply elements within a vector to use as column

Tags: r

I have a data frame :

```
a <- data.frame(c(1:10))
```

I want to add a column like this one:

```
a$Groups <- c("Group1","Group1","Group1",
              "Group2","Group2","Group2","Group2","Group2",
              "Group3","Group3")
```

But I don't want to have to repeat every element.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
a$Groups <- c(rep("Group1", 3),
              rep("Group2", 5),
              rep("Group3", 2))
```

and see

```
?rep
```

Answer (score 0):

An adaptation of @alko989's answer is to use `paste` and `rep`:

```
> paste0("Group", rep(1:3, c(3, 5, 2)))
 [1] "Group1" "Group1" "Group1" "Group2" "Group2" "Group2" "Group2"
 [8] "Group2" "Group3" "Group3"
```

Or, more efficient (I think):

```
rep(paste0("Group", 1:3), c(3, 5, 2))
```